# Puzzling behavior from IF ( ) statement

Tags: javascript, function

I'm a total n00b to JavaScript and fully expect this is something appallingly obvious but I cannot understand why this if ( ) statement is not producing the correct results.

No matter how many characters I input the function returns 'yes' to the console whether 'word' is < or > 2. IF (ha!) anyone can shed any light on this it's greatly appreciated. Code below:

```
var word = document.getElementById('wordChoice').value;  

function flipChk () {

if (word.length < 2) {
    console.log('yes');

} else { 
    console.log('no');
}
}
```

See the fully implemented code here: http://supsean.com/supsean/flipr/flipr.html

Comment: There is something wrong with getting your word input, [this fiddle doesn't have any problems](http://jsfiddle.net/v8tu9v4o/). Check what the value of `document.getElementById('wordChoice').value` is.

Comment: make sure you `.trim()` any user input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried debugging your code and seeing what the value of `word` is when you click the button?

I'm guessing part of your problem is that you're assigning a value to `word` when the page loads but not reading it again when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 1):

Have `word` be set in the function:

```
function flipChk () {
  var word = document.getElementById('wordChoice').value; 

  if (word.length < 2) {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}
```

Your code got the value of `word` only on page load, which was a empty string. Which is why it's always yes.