# Local variables giving global trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm a JS super n00b.

I asked about an aspect of this problem in this post ([Puzzling behavior from IF ( ) statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179239/puzzling-behavior-from-if-statement)) on IF statements but it looks like the actual issue is related to the scope of a variable I've created. It seems that after declaring (what I think is) a global variable, other functions in the code cannot access the variable.

I'm doing JS project/program that prompts a user to input a word and the program reverses the word input.

In the previous post (PP) a user correctly determined that I was getting the 'false' console message (see code) no matter what the length of the word input because I was assigning value the variable when the page loads but not reading it again when the user clicks the button on the page.

If the variable 'word' is local I'm only able to get a 'false' console message and when the variable 'word' is global I'm only able to get a 'ReferenceError.'

Any ideas anyone has are greatly appreciated.

See JS code below:

```
var word = document.getElementById('wordChoice').value;  
var lttrs = [];

function flipFail () {
    alert("Please enter a word of at least two characters.");
    console.log(false);

    var inputErrArr = ['has-error', 'has-feedback'];
    var inputErrFdbk = ['glyphicon', 'glyphicon-remove'];
    wordChoice.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDBAA";

    for (var i = 0; i < inputErrArr.length; i ++) {
        addClass(wordInput, inputErrArr[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < inputErrFdbk.length; i ++) {
        addClass(glyph, inputErrFdbk[i]);
    }

    document.getElementById('wordChoice').value = " ";

}   // END flipFail() 

function flipSuccess (){

    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i ++) {
        lttrs.push(word.charAt(i));
    }

    lttrs.reverse();
    var reversedWord = lttrs.join('')
    alert("Your reversed word is: " + reversedWord);
    console.log(true);

    document.getElementById("flip").innerHTML = "Flip Again!";
    document.getElementById('wordChoice').value = " ";

} // EN flipSuccess () 

function flipChk () {


    if (word.length < 2) {
        flipFail ();

    } else { 
        flipSuccess ();
    }
}
```

See fully implemented code here: http://supsean.com/supsean/flipr/flipr.html

Comment: You're setting `word` when the page is loaded, not when the user enters something into the input field.

Comment: You've got to post the (**relevant**) code **here**.  The whole point of this site is to act as a repository for questions and answers. Your own test site will stop making sense as soon as you have a fix for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `word` in `flipChk()`. You're setting it when the page is first loaded, before the user has entered anything into the form, not when the user clicks on the Flip button.

Then, instead of using a global variable, pass it as an argument to the function. In general, avoid using global variables unless you really have to.

```
function flipChk () {
    var word = document.getElementById('wordChoice').value;
    if (word.length < 2) {
        flipFail ();

    } else { 
        flipSuccess (word);
    }
}

function flipSuccess (word){
    var lttrs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i ++) {
        lttrs.push(word.charAt(i));
    }

    lttrs.reverse();
    var reversedWord = lttrs.join('')
    alert("Your reversed word is: " + reversedWord);
    console.log(true);

    document.getElementById("flip").innerHTML = "Flip Again!";
    document.getElementById('wordChoice').value = " ";

} // EN flipSuccess ()
```

Comment: That indeed helped. Thanks. I thought this was an appropriate time to use a global variable. Anybody with any suggestions on a time when I would *absolutely* need to use a global variable?

Comment: Global variables are useful when you have functions that are called independently, and they need to share information that persists between them.